# Is it possible to create an Estimator with arbitrarily many input Tensors for Predict SignatureDef without placeholders in TensorFlow 2.X?

Tags: tensorflow, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

**The Problem**

I am converting my Tensorflow 1.14 estimator to TensorFlow 2.1. My current workflow involves training my tensorflow model on gcloud's ai-platform [(training on gcloud)](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/training-jobs) and using their model service to deploy my model for online predictions [(model service)](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/deploying-models).

The issue when upgrading to TensorFlow 2 is that they have done away with placeholders, which is affecting my `serving_input_fn` and how I export my estimator model. With tensorflow 2, if I export a model without the use of placeholders, my model's "predict" `SignatureDef` only has a single "examples" tensor whereas previously it had many inputs named appropriately through my `serving_input_fn`.

The previous set up for my estimator was as follows:

```
def serving_input_fn():

    inputs = {
        'feature1': tf.compat.v1.placeholder(shape=None, dtype=tf.string),
        'feature2': tf.compat.v1.placeholder(shape=None, dtype=tf.string),
        'feature3': tf.compat.v1.placeholder(shape=None, dtype=tf.string),
        ...
    }

    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features=split_features, receiver_tensors=inputs)

exporter = tf.estimator.LatestExporter('exporter', serving_input_fn)

eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
    input_fn=lambda: input_eval_fn(args.test_dir),
    exporters=[exporter],
    start_delay_secs=10,
    throttle_secs=0)

...

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

And this has worked fine in the past, it has allowed me to have a multi-input "predict" SignatureDef where I can send a json of the inputs to ai-platforms model service and get predictions back. But since I am trying to not rely on the `tf.compat.v1` library, I want to avoid using placeholders.

**What I've tried**

Following the documentation linked [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#savedmodels_from_estimators) I've replaced my serving_input_fn with the `tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn` method:

```
feature_columns = ... # list of feature columns 
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
  tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns))
```

However, this gives me the following "predict" SignatureDef:

```
signature_def['predict']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['examples'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: input_example_tensor:0
```

whereas before my "predict" SignatureDef was as follows:

```
signature_def['predict']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['feature1'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: Placeholder:0
    inputs['feature2'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: Placeholder_1:0
    inputs['feature3'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: Placeholder_2:0
```

I've also tried using the `tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn`, but my understanding is that this method requires actual Tensors in order to be used instead of a feature spec. Unless I use placeholders, I don't really understand where to grab these serving Tensors from.

**So my main questions are:**

- Is it possible to create a multi-input "predict" signature def from an estimator model without using placeholders in Tensorflow 2?
- If it is not possible, how am I supposed to provide the instances to gcloud predictions service for the "examples" tensor in the "predict" signature def?

Thanks!